# Tabhost error in getting in to my activity

Tags: android, android-tabhost

When I am trying to get the tab host in my activity it is showing the error that do you forget to call `public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)`?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private Resources res;
    private TabHost tabHost;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

            tabHost.setup();

        res = getResources();

        Intent intentContact = new Intent().setClass(this,
                tabOne_Activity.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecContact = tabHost.newTabSpec("Chat")
                .setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setContent(intentContact);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecContact);

        Intent intentChat = new Intent().setClass(this, tabTwo_Activity.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecChat = tabHost.newTabSpec("Chat")
                .setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setContent(intentChat);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecChat);

        Intent intentProfile = new Intent().setClass(this,
                tabThree_Activity.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecProfile = tabHost.newTabSpec("Chat")
                .setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setContent(intentProfile);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecProfile);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);


    }
}
```

Comment: move  `tabHost.setup();` at last after setting up all the tabs

Comment: Replace Tabhost findviewById with this  mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

Comment: @M D then it is showing the null pointer exception   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)

Comment: @Mert Serimer but i use tabhost in my layout not fragment tabhost       <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

Comment: Your are in FragmentActivity. Can you try what i wrote there pls.

Comment: @Mert Serimer  then it is showing the error  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TabHost cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost

Comment: Change your variable type to FragmentTabHost

Comment: You can refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461889/tabs-content-in-android-fragments/21462009#21462009

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use tabhost.For that you must extend **TabActivity**.

OR

Write the below code in onCreate():

```
LocalActivityManager mlam = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
        mlam.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // tabHost = getTabHost();
        //tabHost.setup();
        tabHost.setup(mlam);
```

Comment: it works :) but when i am writing something in edit text on tab2  and then switing the tab 1 the state of edit text of tab 2 is loose plz hepl me how to maintain the state

Comment: you have to save the text in preference or sqlite...it cannot hold the state by itself magically.