# TabHost Image and text is not displaying

Tags: android

```
TabHost.TabSpec allSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(ALL_SERVICES);
allSpec.setIndicator("Hello World",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_inbox));
intentServices = new Intent(this, InboxActivity.class);
allSpec.setContent(intentServices);
tabHost.add(allSpec);
```

Comment: http://www.whatsoniphone.com/blog/android-app-development-tabbed-activities/

Comment: I wanted inside FragmentActivity not in TabActivity

Comment: Why are you using a TabHost? The whole TabHost Api is deprecated for a long time now. You should use  the action bar for that: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

Comment: Then you can use this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360054/tabhost-error-in-getting-in-to-my-activity/28360482#28360482

Comment: @Kgandroid - I have already done that but my problem is Image and text in Tab. It show only text

Comment: if I use the same code in activity class I see both image and text but when I see in ActionBarActivity Class its showing only One Either Image or Text. So can anyOne help me with the ActionBarActivity Class.